# Netty write several messages through one channel

Tags: java, netty, channel

I'm newbie in Netty. I want send several messages through one channel in this way

```
channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("TBD", CharsetUtil.UTF_8)).sync()
channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("TBD1", CharsetUtil.UTF_8)).sync()
```

But this code produce java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException. 
How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the Channel was closed before. You should investigate the cause for this.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer to the question

Comment: I just found the reason in channel.close at server side