# Netty write several messages

Tags: java, netty, channel

I have the same issue than here ([Netty write several messages through one channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308826/netty-write-several-messages-through-one-channel/27212434)) and I can't solve it. Here you are some cases:

- I can send several messages from client-side, and the server receives only if it doesn't respond.
- If I send a message to the server and it treats (with handler), generates, and writeAndFlush the response, the channel will switch to closed and I can't send more messages from client-side.
- If I send a message from client with write() method, the message doesn't arrive to server because flush is necessary. It doesn't close the channel.

It looks like that the problem is on the server-side when generates a response and writeAndFlush.

I'm developing an RTSP Client/Server and this protocol is based on HTTP/1.1 Following the Netty documentation for Snoop Http Server (http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html), if you use the keep-alive option, the messages only write and doesn't flush. In my use of case, I repeat, the messages don't arrive to the server.

Here you are some code:

> Client-Side

```
    // Bootstrap
    public RtspClient(String host, String port) throws NumberFormatException, InterruptedException{
                  // Configure the client.
                  EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
                  try {
                      b = new Bootstrap();
                      b.group(group)
                       .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                       .handler(new RtspClientInitializer());

                      ch = b.connect(host, Integer.parseInt(port)).sync().channel();

                 } finally {
                     // Shut down executor threads to exit.
                     // group.shutdownGracefully();
                 }
    }

     // Channel Pipeline definition
     class RtspClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
        @Override
          public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
              ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
              p.addLast("encoder", new RtspRequestEncoder());
              p.addLast("decoder", new RtspResponseDecoder());
              p.addLast("handler", new RtspClientHandler());
          }
      }

      // The method which sends RTSP OPTIONS protocol method
      public void sendOptions() throws InterruptedException{

        // HTTP/RTSP request.
        DefaultFullHttpRequest request = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(
        RtspVersions.RTSP_1_0, RtspMethods.OPTIONS, "*");
        request.headers().set(RtspHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, RtspHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
        request.headers().set(RtspHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, request.content().readableBytes());
        request.headers().set(RtspHeaders.Names.CSEQ, this.CSeq);
        this.CSeq++;

        // Write to channel

        System.out.println("Request: ------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(request.toString());
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

        ch.writeAndFlush(request);

      }
```

> Server-Side

```
    // Bootstrap
    public void initRtspServer() throws InterruptedException{
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childHandler(new RtspServerInitializer());

            ChannelFuture cf = b.bind(this.port);

            System.err.println("RTSP Server run at this URL: " +
                    "rtsp" + "://127.0.0.1:" + this.port + '/');

            cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }


    // Channel Pipeline definition
    class RtspServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
            p.addLast("decoder",new RtspRequestDecoder());
            p.addLast("encoder",new RtspResponseEncoder());
            p.addLast("handler",new RtspServerHandler());
        }
     }

     // In this case I only handle the OPTIONS method on server-side
     class RtspServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest> {

        private HttpRequest request;
        private FullHttpResponse response;

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest request)
                throws Exception {

        this.response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(RTSP_1_0,OK);
            String sequence = request.headers().get(RtspHeaders.Names.CSEQ);
            this.response.headers().set(RtspHeaders.Names.CSEQ, sequence);
            this.response.headers().set(RtspHeaders.Names.PUBLIC, "OPTIONS,SETUP,TEARDOWN,PLAY");
            ctx.writeAndFlush(response).isSuccess(); // I think server closes the channel here

        }
    }
```

If I do the following in the main class from client:

```
        RtspClient client = new RtspClient("127.0.0.1","554");
        client.sendOptions();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        client.sendOptions();
```

the second sendOptions() do nothing.

With Netty 3.2 I didn't have this problem, It works properly with send() method.

Comment: Netty 4's HTTP decoder always produces `HttpMessage` + 1 or more `HttpContent`. If you want Netty to merge them into a single `FullHttpMessage`, insert `HttpObjectAggregator` into the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you trustin, my problem was that the method exceptionCaught in the client-side handler closed the channel by default when an exception happens.

Now is solved.

Comment: You could probably update your question and post a self-answer for future usefulness? :-)